# How to loop on value in a data frame and insert zeros in the middle

Tags: python, validation, data-science, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have a value in a column 'ACCOUNT_N0', it consists of 14 digits I want them to be 16 digits by inserting 2 zeros in the middle, one in the 4th position and the other in the 8th position
example:
This is the value: 33322288888888
The output: 3330222088888888

What i have found is inserting zeros at the beginning of the number, using:

```
df['ACCOUNT_NO'].astype(str).str.zfill(16)
```

I want to know how to insert in the 4th position and the 8th position

Comment: Do you want a single 0 in the middle or do you want 0s at the 4th and 8th position like this `3330222880888888`?

Comment: thank you for getting back to me, yes i want 2 zeros, one in the 4th position and another in the 8th position like this : 3330222088888888

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable (you cannot change a string's value). So you can use slicing to add the `0`s in the right position as so:

```
my_str[:4] + "0" + my_str[4:8] + "0" + my_str[8:]
```

In your pandas dataframe, you could apply this concept like this:

```
df['ACCOUNT_NO'] = df['ACCOUNT_NO'].astype(str)
df['ACCOUNT_NO'] = df['ACCOUNT_NO'].str[:4] + "0" + df['ACCOUNT_NO'].str[4:8] + "0" + df['ACCOUNT_NO'].str[8:]
```

Full code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ACCOUNT_NO"])
df["ACCOUNT_NO"] = ["33322288888888"]
df['ACCOUNT_NO'] = df['ACCOUNT_NO'].astype(str)
df['ACCOUNT_NO'] = df['ACCOUNT_NO'].str[:4] + "0" + df['ACCOUNT_NO'].str[4:8] + "0" + df['ACCOUNT_NO'].str[8:]
```

**Output**:

Before

[image: before]

After

[image: after]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that take in input the digits(as string) and put the '0' in the positions that you want, like this:

```
def insert_0(text):
    tmp = text
    text = tmp[0:3] + '0' + tmp[3:7] + '0' + tmp[7:]
    return text
```

And than in the main you call it using DataFrame.apply(), like this:

```
df['ACCOUNT_NO'] = df['ACCOUNT_NO'].astype(str)
df['ACCOUNT_NO'] = df['ACCOUNT_NO'].apply(insert_0)
```

Hope it could be useful.